# Find all $x$ such that the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(nx)}{\ln(n)}}$$

I want to find all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that the series converges. I only know that the series converges for $x=\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}$ 
But I don't know for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, it diverges quite clearly.

Otherwise, the series converges. Here is a guide as to why.

1. **Show that $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(nx) \leq \frac{\cos(Nx/2)\sin\left((N+1)x/2\right)}{\sin(x/2)}$.**

   You can do this by considering $\cos(nx)$ as the real part of $e^{inx}$ and using geometric series.
2. **Use [Dirichlet's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).**

   As (just now) Ted Shifrin has mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You might find [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) helpful.