# For what values of $x$ does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sin^2(nx)}{n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sin^2(nx)}{n}$, for which values $x\in\mathbb{R}$  does the series converge?

When $x=0$, $2\sin^2(nx)=0$, so this converges. I don't think there are any other values.

Comment: $x=k\pi$ clearly works just as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant modulo $\pi$. How can I prove that for other values, the series diverges?

Comment: You could start by proving that a positive proportion of the values $nx$ modulo $\pi$ lie between $\frac\pi4$ and $\frac{3\pi}4$, for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you write the series as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos 2nx}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos 2nx}{n}$,

the first term diverges and the second term converges by Dirichlet's test (if x is not a multiple of $\pi$);

so 
the series diverges (if x is not a multiple of $\pi$).

---

One way to show that the sequence $\displaystyle s_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(2nx)$ is bounded is to use the equation

$\;\;\;\;2\cos(2nx)\sin x=\sin(2nx+x)-\sin(2nx-x)$, so that

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(2nx)=\frac{1}{2\sin x}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin((2n-1)x)\right]=\frac{1}{2\sin x}\left[\sin((2N+1)x)-\sin x\right]$

and therefore $\displaystyle|s_N|\le\frac{1}{|\sin x|}=|\csc x|\;\;$ if x is not a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: What bound do we use on $\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \cos(2nx)\right|$ to apply Dirichlet's test?

Comment: Here is a reference that gives a bound for this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744125